# Populating local array from callback: synchronization issues?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, callback, jquery-callback

Here's the deal:

I populate a local array in a callback like so:

```
var datasource = datasources[id];
var contexts = [];

datasource.data($selected.parent().data(), function (items) {
          var dataarr = items.data;
          for (var i = 0; i < dataarr.length; ++i) {
               contexts.push(dataarr[i]);
          }
      });

foo(contexts);
```

Now, in foo, I run a simple check like:

```
function foo(contexts) {
    if (contexts.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
}
```

If I break at the return statement above, contexts.length is in fact, greater than 2. Similarly, if I run the code step by step in a debugger, everything works as expected.

This make me suspect that when not running in a debugger, this code is being executed before the callback has completed.

Fine. But how can I control the execution order? Or, perhaps, is there a better paradigm to go about this if the only way I know can acquire `items.data` is from within that callback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the context here a little bit, but if you want your method `foo` to be called after the array has been populated, why not call it after the for loop? like so:

```
datasource.data($selected.parent().data(), function (items) {
      var dataarr = items.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < dataarr.length; ++i) {
           contexts.push(dataarr[i]);
      }
      foo(contexts);
  });
```

if you're uncomfortable with that, look at [PubSubJS](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) which allows you to emit events and handle them asynchronously. I wrote an article about it's usage [here](https://coderwall.com/p/w8pzug).

**Edit**: An example:

```
datasource.data($selected.parent().data(), function (items) {
      var dataarr = items.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < dataarr.length; ++i) {
           contexts.push(dataarr[i]);
      }
      PubSub.publish('contextsPopulated', contexts);
  });
```

and then modify `foo` as:

```
function foo(message, contexts) {
    if (contexts.length < 2) {
        return;
    }
}
```

now register foo to be called whenever `'contextsPopulated'` is signalled.

```
PubSub.subscribe('contextsPopulated', foo);
```